# Why a click function of a web page element doesn't work (using Selenium module of Python)?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to automate a task which can save me thousands of clicks.

I searched a bit for available modules in Python and I have selected to work with Selenium.

I installed Firefox drivers and did some progress but I am stuck for a long time. I finally gave up, opened a Stack Overflow account and wanted to bring this problem into this helpful medium.

My code can successfully do some clicks, but I could not make the code click a button like element. I have to click such items so that page opens some new elements. (Hopefully I am going to click on these new elements to save some excels files automatically).

Here is the part which works as expected:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
url =  "https://www.tbb.org.tr/tr/bankacilik/banka-ve-sektor-bilgileri/istatistiki-raporlar/59"
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(2)

bank_reports_element_xpath = "//*[@title=  'Tüm Raporlar']"
bank_reports_element = browser.find_element_by_xpath(bank_reports_element_xpath)
bank_reports_element.click()
time.sleep(2)

second_item = "//div[@data-catid = '52']"
finance_tables_element = browser.find_element_by_xpath(second_item)
finance_tables_element.click()

years_item = "//div[@class = 'years']"
years_element = finance_tables_element.find_element_by_xpath(years_item)
year_elements = years_element.find_elements_by_xpath("a")
```

There I would like to click on the years.
[a screenshot of the years that I can't click using Selenium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sM5vW.jpg)

As an example, I get the element related to year 2004.

```
year2004 = year_elements[2]
```

Issuing a    *year2004.click()*    command gives an ElementNotInteractableException exception.

```
year2004.click()  # ElementNotInteractableException: Element could not be scrolled into view
```

Based on searching similar posts, I tried the following (executing the click via javascript). I got no error but it does not do anything. When I click the year2004 button with mouse, a list pops-up in the page. But when I run the below code, no list pops up in the page.

```
browser.implicitly_wait(4)
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", year2004)
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", year2004)
```

I tried also the following code. I get "TypeError: rect is undefined"

```
browser.implicitly_wait(4)
action = ActionChains(browser)
action.move_to_element(year2004)       # gives: TypeError: rect is undefined
action.click(on_element = year2004)    # gives: TypeError: rect is undefined
action.perform()
```

I tried using Chrome Driver and got similar results. The errors definitions were not exactly the same. Instead of the above "rect is undefined" error, Chrome error is like: "Javascript error: Failed to execute 'elementsFromPoints' on 'Document': Provided double value is non-finite"

I don't know if it is relevant but   *year2004.location*   dictionary has a 0 value for "x".

I would appreciate any answer,

Keep safe

Comment: from what i have heard it could be that there are elements on top of button that block the click. My solution (workaround) would be to use tabs in selenium. so u count how many times you have to press tab and then when you are on element switch to focused element and then press enter all that in selenium script.

Comment: try with: years_element.find_elements_by_xpath(".//a")  (but you may need a webdriverwait depending on how the site works...)  You should include that page's markup in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this xpath will give you all the elements of year in 52 category

```
//div[@data-catid='52']/descendant-or-self::*/div[@class='years']/child::a
```

for scrolling try

```
browser.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```

I checked manually and page down button is working for me press it twice for desire element

Comment: the “send keys” idea worked, thanks